# Django Rest Framework save data into not default database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have model:

```
class TableUser(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 't_users'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializer look like:

```
class UserListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


class Meta:
    model = TableUser
    fields = ('name', 'lastname')
```

I would like to save new data into database (not default)

```
{
    "name": "one",
    "lastname": "two"
}
```

Settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'remote': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',

        'NAME': 'test_db',

        'USER': 'admin',

        'PASSWORD': 'admin123!',

        'HOST': 'localhost',


    }
}
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def saveuser(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        saveserialize=UserListSerializer(data=request.data)
        if saveserialize.is_valid():
            saveserialize.save(using='remote')
            return Response(saveserialize.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(saveserialize.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

i get:

*t_users() got an unexpected keyword argument 'using'*

if I change

**saveserialize=UserListSerializer(data=request.data)**

to

**saveserialize=UserListSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)**

then I get

*Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `UserListSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.*

Please help me, what am I doing wrong